# Asp mvc update view when database was changed

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, time

If is possible do update view, when database was changed using ajax? Example i have auction and list item and when one person bid, then an anothers persons view was refresh.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want something like [signalR](http://signalr.net/). Microsoft has some pretty good [turorials](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Comment: Thanks for answer but i write Engineering work and I want compare two technologies: ajax and web socket (measue responsoe time). And I want use ajax

Comment: If that's the case you should edit your original question because after reading your comment it's not very clear what your actual question is.